# Android database leak found

Tags: android, database, getwritabledatabase

When i enter another activity to insert new item into the database,return and then go in that activity it gives me an error:

```
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134): Leak found
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134): java.lang.IllegalStateException: /data/data/com.app.myapp/databases/BabyApp.db SQLiteDatabase created and never closed
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1695)
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:739)
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:761)
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:754)
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134):  at android.app.ApplicationContext.openOrCreateDatabase(ApplicationContext.java:473)
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:193)
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134):  at com.app.myapp.DatabaseHelper.open(DatabaseHelper.java:121)
04-03 18:53:26.914: E/Database(18134):  at com.app.myapp.SettingsActivity.init(SettingsActivity.java:80)
```

here is the DatabaseHelper.java:121

```
database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

here is the SettingsActivity line 80 code:

```
if (!db.isOpen())
            db.open();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you do execute `db.close();` in order to close your database before switching to another activity

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    //closing database connection
    if(db != null)
        db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close it too...  Close it when an Exception occurs or in any case it should never be left open since its System resource